Conflict When use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection vs Npgsql in Net 4.8
I'm developing an application that runs on AutoCAD using .NET Framework 4.8 and Npgsql, following the MVVM pattern. In my project, I use Dependency Injection (DI) to manage the lifecycle of objects through Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection. However, when I use this DI framework, I encounter a conflict and receive the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral...'

If I remove Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, the program runs fine. I would like to know if there's a way to continue using DI in my project while ensuring Npgsql works without issues. I've also tried using Autofac for DI, but I encountered a similar error.
I also tried follow this answer but not working
I tried binding like this:
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity
    name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions"
    publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect
    oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0"
    newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>

but it's not working.
Is there a solution to this problem?
I still want to use Dependency Injection (DI) and Npgsql. Is there a way to use both without causing conflicts or encountering the error Could not load file or assembly ?'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0 Culture=neutral

Seems like you're missing some binding redirects.

I tried binding like this 


   but it's not working.  Could you please explain more details?

I bet the full exception message is "Could not load file or assembly ... or one of its dependencies". The problem could, therefore, very well lie in one of System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions's dependencies. I struggled with this myself a few years ago and found it very difficult to find the correct set of binding redirects as there is a quite complex dependency graph below it.

You could also consider suppressing binding redirects completely using AssemblyResolve. I use this method in my applications and it prevents me from having to specify a single binding redirect.

I tried update Version of Npgsql , error above solved but new other error.System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.  it's my Repository https://github.com/NguyenVung2305/SketchRoute  please give me some advice!
